# CSS Enter Animation for Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this slide in animation which works on hovering event for now. But now i want that animation to work as soon as page is loaded and whenever window width is changed to below 900px it should slide out.

Here is my Html:

```
<div class="left-nav pack-container slide-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="left-nav-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sections</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Travels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Recently Viewed</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#left-nav-list {
position: relative;
left: -350px;
transition: 1s;
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
}

.slide-wrapper:hover #left-nav-list {
transition: 1s;
left:0;
}
```

i tried by fetching the id and do classList.add, but had no luck with it.

Used following additionals:

- AngularJS
- Bootstrap

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3zr7a0v/)

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a example in jsfiddle and show it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it some default, non-loaded class, and then unset that class when the window loads. And this is how the CSS should look like:

```
#left-nav-list {
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  left:0;
}

#left-nav-list.notLoaded {
  left: -350px;
}
```

---

Here's a simple example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('left-nav-list').classList.remove('notLoaded');
}
```

```css
#left-nav-list {
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  left:0;
}

#left-nav-list.notLoaded {
  left: -350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="left-nav pack-container slide-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked notLoaded" id="left-nav-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sections</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Travels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Recently Viewed</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k3zr7a0v/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:400px) {

   #left-nav-list {
    transition: 1s;
    left:0px !important;
    }

}​
```

Comment: Thanks man this worked for me, i used this
   
@media (max-width:900px) {

   #left-nav-list {
    transition: 1s;
    left:-350px !important;
    }
  }
i worked, but whenever it slides back